# Reproduce the `expand.grid` function from R in Julia

Tags: r, combinations, julia

`expand.grid` is a very handy function in `R` for calculating all possible combinations of several list. Here is how it works:

```
> x = c(1,2,3)
> y = c("a","b")
> z = c(10,12)
> d = expand.grid(x,y,z)
> d
   Var1 Var2 Var3
1     1    a   10
2     2    a   10
3     3    a   10
4     1    b   10
5     2    b   10
6     3    b   10
7     1    a   12
8     2    a   12
9     3    a   12
10    1    b   12
11    2    b   12
12    3    b   12
```

How can I reproduce this function in Julia?

Comment: I thought about building  `n` nested loops where `n` is the number of variables (3: `x`,`y`,`z` in my above example). Each loop would iterate through the number of unique values in each variable but I got confused because I can't know in advance how many loops I need. So I was thinking about building a function that calls itself, but 1) I don't know if this is feasible in Julia and 2) that sounds like a stupidly complicated solution that will probably not be very performent. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Have you seen how R's expand.grid does it? It loops over the number of args, adding a column in each iteration which is a twisty subsetting of the source column with all sorts of nested rep's and so on...

Comment: Check [**here**](http://www.scolvin.com/juliabyexample/): "`repeat` can be useful to expand a grid as in R's `expand.grid()` function", and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581263/is-there-outer-map-function-in-julia): "Is there some function analog of `expand.grid` from R" (first two google hits...)

Comment: @Henrik, first link isn't very general (although does work), second link is definitely good although does rely on a package.

Comment: @IainDunning Thanks for your comment. My comment was intended as a small poke to OP that they easily could have found some Julia code to put in the question (what-have-you-tried) and then explained why it it didn't meet their needs, e.g. 'I wish something more general', 'however, this solution relies on a package' (i.e. exactly your remarks). Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Henrik's comment:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = ["a","b"]
z = [10,12]
d = collect(Iterators.product(x,y,z))
```

Here is another solution using list comprehension

```
reshape([ [x,y,z]  for x=x, y=y, z=z ],length(x)*length(y)*length(z))
```

Comment: Should note that the first requires a package, and the second is special cased for a finite set of lists (although thats fine for any particular case)

Comment: Yes indeed! I added the `using Iterators`. Thank you!

Comment: The above comments are now out of date as of Julia 1.1 as the iterators are now built into the main Julia with the Iterators namespace. You just write Iterators.product.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my completely(?) general solution, using recursion, varargs, and splatting:

```
function expandgrid(args...)
    if length(args) == 0
        return Any[]
    elseif length(args) == 1
        return args[1]
    else
        rest = expandgrid(args[2:end]...)
        ret  = Any[]
        for i in args[1]
            for r in rest
                push!(ret, vcat(i,r))
            end
        end
        return ret
    end
end

eg = expandgrid([1,2,3], ["a","b"], [10,12])
@assert length(eg) == 3*2*2
@show eg
```

This gives an array of arrays, but you could combine that into a matrix trivially if thats what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is rather an old question, but I also did convert the expand.grid function from R to Julia almost line by line few days before finding this post...
It can still be interesting for someone because it returns a `DataFrame`, which can be more convenient.
Here is the [link to the Gist](https://gist.github.com/VEZY/babd21542ba13ff887ebf2299cab43cc), and here is the code just in case:

````
using DataFrames

"""
Create a Data Frame from All Combinations of Factor Variables (see R's base::expand.grid)
# Arguments
... Array, Dict, or Tuple containing at least one value
# Return
A DataFrame containing one row for each combination of the supplied argument. The first factors vary fastest.
# Examples
```julia
expand_grid([1,2],["owl","cat"])
expand_grid((1,2),("owl","cat"))
expand_grid((1,2)) # -> Returns a DataFrame with 2 rows of 1 and 2.
```
"""
function expand_grid(args...)
    nargs= length(args)

    if nargs == 0
      error("expand_grid need at least one argument")
    end

    iArgs= 1:nargs
    nmc= "Var" .* string.(iArgs)
    nm= nmc
    d= map(length, args)
    orep= prod(d)
    rep_fac= [1]
    # cargs = []

    if orep == 0
        error("One or more argument(s) have a length of 0")
    end

    cargs= Array{Any}(undef,orep,nargs)

    for i in iArgs
        x= args[i]
        nx= length(x)
        orep= Int(orep/nx)
        mapped_nx= vcat(map((x,y) -> repeat([x],y), collect(1:nx), repeat(rep_fac,nx))...)
        cargs[:,i] .= x[repeat(mapped_nx,orep)]
        rep_fac= rep_fac * nx
    end

    convert(DataFrame,cargs)
end
````

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but in case someone is still looking for a solution that works like the R expand.grid function (i.e. passing a list of named variables of any type and returning a data frame with the variable names as column names, each column of the type of the original variable, and all possible combinations of the different variables), this is my Julia-newbie attempt at it:

```
using DataFrames

function expand_grid(; iters...)
    var_names = collect(keys(iters))
    var_itr = [1:length(x) for x in iters.data]
    var_ix = vcat([collect(x)' for x in Iterators.product(var_itr...)]...)
    out = DataFrame()
    for i = 1:length(var_names)
        out[:,var_names[i]] = collect(iters[i])[var_ix[:,i]]
    end
    return out
end

expand_grid(a=1:2, b=1.0:5.0, c=["one", "two", "three", "four"])
```

There is most likely a more efficient or cleaner way to do this but this is the best I could come up with that would give me what I expect from the R function.

Answer (score 0):

```
using DataFrames

function expand_grid(; kw...)
  values = [v for (_, v) in kw]
  names = keys(kw) |> collect
  DataFrame(collect(Iterators.product(values...))[:], names)
end

julia> dims = (x = 1:2, y = [3, 4], z = ["a", "b", "c"]);

julia> expand_grid(;dims...)
12×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x      y      z      
     │ Int64  Int64  String 
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │     1      3  a
   2 │     2      3  a
   3 │     1      4  a
   4 │     2      4  a
   5 │     1      3  b
   6 │     2      3  b
   7 │     1      4  b
   8 │     2      4  b
   9 │     1      3  c
  10 │     2      3  c
  11 │     1      4  c
  12 │     2      4  c
```